# How to read XML using Linq with Single root and nested child and siblings in it

Tags: c#, linq

How to read the elements inside nested childs and siblings in a single root using LINQ

My Xml file format

```
<Config xmlns="urn:Configuration">
    <Group name="Model" version="1.01" source="Barium">
      <Group tag="MeterSystem" type="option">
        <Entry readonly="1" type="string">PW_TP_STANDARD</Entry>
      </Group>
      <Group tag="Detector" type="option">
        <Entry readonly="1" type="string">SD770</Entry>
      </Group>
      <Group tag="VXtypeOpt" type="option">
        <Entry type="string">Vx88</Entry>
      </Group>
      <Group tag="FlowDirectionOpt" type="option">
        <Entry type="string">Upwards</Entry>
      </Group>
  </Group>

  <Group name="Config">
    <Entry name="Configuration name" type="string">Default</Entry>
  </Group>
```

My C# Code to read the Xml structure

```
List<string> fpxmls = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@_fpxml_path, "*.xml",
                                                   SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                         .ToList<string>();
foreach (var _file in fpxmls)
{
    var MyFPXMLDoc = XDocument.Load(@_file);
    var Config = (from config in MyFPXMLDoc .Descendants("Group")
                  select new
                  {
                      source= (string) config.Attribute("source"),
                      // How should I proceed?
                      // Using descendants doesnt give any items to  Config
                      // How to extract VxMeterSize= (string)g.(?).(?)// shud return Vx88
                  });
    ...
}
```

Comment: For future questions, please take more time to format your code and XML pleasantly.#

Comment: @ Jon Skeet - Sure i will take a note of it. I am beginner to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've ignored the namespace which is defaulted in `Config`. All of the `Group` elements are in that namespace, but you're looking for descendantse *without* a namespace.

You want:

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:Configuration";
var query = from config in MyFPXMLDoc.Descendants(ns + "Group")
            ...;
```

Comment: @ Jon Skeet - Thanks a lot for the solution which i expected.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet - How to extract the data VX88 inside the entry tag of a group

Comment: @ShrivatsanRangarajan: You would use `g.Element(ns + "Entry")` within the appropriate element. But if you have follow-up questions, those should usually be asked *as new questions*.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet - Ok jon noted.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878935/how-to-read-and-extract-large-xml-data-using-linq-with-single-namespace-for-nest                        appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

There is default namespace defined in your xml file. You can get use [XElement.GetDefaultNamespace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.getdefaultnamespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get default namespace of root node. Then you should specify namespace as part of node name when selecting groups:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var groups = from g in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Group")
             select new
             {
                 Source = (string)g.Attribute("source"),
                 Entry = (string)g.Element(ns + "Entry")
             };
```

NOTE: `Group` is only local name of node. Full name will be `{urn:Configuration}Group`.

Comment: @ Sergey Thanks a lot for the solution which i expected. I was totally unaware of the namespace.

Comment: I am finding fishy to extract this value -Vx88 . Should i consider  VxMeterSize = (string)g.FirstNode.Parent for extracting Vx88 value ? but it gives all the values inside the entry tags

Comment: @ShrivatsanRangarajan no problem, updated query to get `Vx88` value

Comment: g = { Source = "Barium", Entry = "0" } I am getting 0 as the value . Something wrong . I think we are missing some more element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878935/how-to-read-and-extract-large-xml-data-using-linq-with-single-namespace-for-nest

Comment: Entry = (string)g.Element(ns + "Group").Element(ns + "Entry"), gives me Entry = "PW_TP_STANDARD"  .... How to generically extract other entry

Comment: @ Sergey Appreciate your reply.

Comment: @ShrivatsanRangarajan sorry, was AFK. What you mean by extracting other entry? Query above extracts all entries